# Spring Integration: call REST endpoint using outbound gateway with oAuth?

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, spring-integration, microsoft-dynamics

I have been using SI outbound gateway to call a REST endpoint protected using NTLM (Microsoft Dynamics backend). It was simple enough, just configure the HttpComponentsMessageSender credentials to use Apache HttpClient's NTCredentials, and it works transparently.

Now however they've gone and protected it with ADFS, which requires oAuth 2.0 authentication. I know Apache HttpClient (which is what SI / Rest Template uses at a lower level) doesn't support oAuth out of the box, there is no oAuth AuthScheme. There *is* an oAuth 1.0 AuthScheme implemented on oauth.net, but as I said, I need oAuth 2.0.

So I guess what I'm asking is, does anyone know of an oAuth 2,0 AuthScheme that can be plugged into Apache HttpClient, for use with SI? Or alternatively, would it be possible to somehow plug in [Google's oAuth client](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-oauth-java-client/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<int-http:outbound-gateway>` supports `rest-template` attribute for injection `RestTemplate` implementation.

So, consider to use [Spring Security OAuth](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/) project and its [OAuth2RestTemplate](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/OAuth2RestTemplate.java).

Comment: Aha! I was also looking at Spring Security OAuth but had no idea you could just plug it into the outbound gateway like that, using OAuth2RestTemplate.

Many thanks for the tip, off to try to integrate ...